Python 3.13 with Websockets and asyncio - how to close connection properly
I am using python 3.13 with the rewritten asyncio and library websockets to download prices.
The issue is once the data is received the websocket connection is not closed.
Here is the code snippet:
async def main():
    async for websocket in connect(
        ws_connection_url,
        ping_interval=20,
        ping_timeout=20,
        compression=None,
        close_timeout=10,
        ssl=ssl_context,
        ):
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg_auth))
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg_public_ticker))
        async for message in websocket:
            r = await websocket.recv(message)            
            print(r)
asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)

Please, could you assist and direct me in the right direction to solve this issue?
Thanks, Greetings, Peter
I tried several loop constructs but without success
